# Filling in a search box and then clicking on the autocomplete

Tags: capybara

I am having trouble filling in and clicking this search box

```
<input type="text" name="js-emu-operation-search" id="js-emu-operation-search" placeholder="Enter service name" autocomplete="off">
```

I have tried using

```
internet.fill_in('js-emu-operation-search', :with => "Alternator Replacement")
```

but it does not work. After that is filled in though I am also wondering how to click on the first autocomplete option.

Comment: What do you mean by “does not work”? Do you get an error, does it just not show the autocomplete you expect, etc? What JS library are you using for the auto-suggest widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with autocompletes can be pretty difficult, depending on how it's implemented.  Some tricks I've used in the past:

- Click the input before sending text to it

  `find('#js-emu-operation-search').click()`
- Try using the underlying element methods instead of the `fill_in` wrapper, e.g.

  `find('#js-emu-operation-search').set("Alternator Replacement")`
- Select from the dropdown options with `find("#results-pane", text: "My Result").click`, or if you get really desperate, make sure there's only a single result and select it with the down arrow, `find('#js-emu-operation-search').native.send_keys(:arrow_down)`

Disclaimer: My capybara is getting rusty, may have to tinker.  If you're working on a team, I've also had good luck dragging another developer into it, preferably the guy who implemented the autocomplete.